# Generate a unique 2-byte integer from three integers

Tags: c#, unique, unique-key

I have three integers:

- First number ranges from 1-600
- Second number ranges from 0-4
- Third number ranges from 0-14

I need to generate a 2-byte unique integer from the above integers such that:

- Using the same number again would result in the same number
- Ability to get back all three numbers from the unique number
- Unique number should be > 0 && < 32768 (2-byte)

I have searched for solutions, but most solution doubles the number of bytes from 2 to 4 bytes which is not an option in my case.

Comment: As others mentioned already, the combination of ranges [1..600], [0..4] and [0..14] results in 45000 possible values, too much for your range (0..32768), so absolute uniqueness is impossible with that constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's convert the first range to 0-599, marked as `first-1` below. Then, all you need to do is multiply the numbers together, using range maximums as multipliers:

```
range_of_first = 599 + 1 = 600
range_of_second = 4 + 1 = 5
range_of_third = 14 + 1 = 15

(first-1) + range_of_first * second + range_of_first * range_of_second * third
= (first-1) + 600*second + 600*5*third
= result
```

Maximum value you can get is 599 + 600 * 4 + 600 * 5 * 14 = **44999**

This does not fit as is into a signed 2 byte integer (-32768..32767). It fits into 2 byte unsigned integer (0..65535).

If you have to fit it into a signed integer, then easiest is to do calculcation in 32 bits, then substract (44999-32768) from the result, so it will fit into range of 2-byte signed integer. Then before decoding do reverse.

And for the opposite, you need division and reminder:

```
first = result % range_of_first + 1 // +1 to get values 1..600
second = result / range_of_first % range_of_second
third = result / range_of_first / range_of_second // % range_of_third redundant
```

Above all numbers are assumed to be non-negative, and usual integer division rounding is assumed, that is just chopping off any decimals.

Comment: I implemented everything exactly as you described it but on numbers that exceeds 32768, when i subtract them i got duplicate numbers.

Comment: @ykh Note that I updated the answer an hour ago, there was a mistake in multiplication. Anyway, can you give an example of two sets of 3 numbers, where you get duplicate?

Comment: @ykh The idea is not to subtract from values that are too large, but from all values, therefore giving you negative values in some cases. If you really insist that you want positive 15bit values (0..32768), then your task is impossible without giving up uniqueness.

Comment: I think that make sense now. I was trying to fix the issue but this is very hard without having negative numbers. The numbers that gave me the duplicate were 233,0,0 and that is just one set. There are a lot of duplicates when i subtract. Anyhow, i will use negative numbers

Comment: @ykh So, for those numbers, unadjusted result is `((233-1)+0*600+0*600*5)=232`. Then you adjust it for 2-byte signed integer, `232-(44999-32767) = -12000`, which you store or whatever. Then to decode, you first reverse the adjustment: `-12000 - (44999-32767) = 232`, which when decoded should give `233,0,0`.

Comment: @ykh Btw, you should really write "unit tests" for a function like this. And you don't need any fancy testing framework for that either, simply write a test program, which calls the encoding and decoding functions for all interesting values (1,0,0; 600,4,14 and all combinations of these), and check that you get the original 3 numbers back for all.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them into strings with zero padding. Concatenate them after padding with zeroes. Then convert them back into an integer.

So 20-1-8 would become "020108" and then 20108 when you turn it into an integer.

To get the numbers back, reconvert into string and parse from right to left based on number of digits.

Comment: Assume that the number is 500-1-14. That would be 050001014. Convert it integer..it would be 50001014 which is no longer a 2-byte integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think hyde means (first-1) + range_of_first * second + range_of_first * range_of_second * third
= (first-1) + 600*second + 600*5*third
 = (first-1) + 600*second + 3000*third .

You need to store 45000 different values, so you just can't fit them into 2 signed bytes, but they would fit into 2 unsigned bytes.